# Undocumented error 86 on twitter rest api

Tags: android, twitter

i have an Android/Iphone app that retrieves data from Twitter rest api 1.1.

A week ago the android app stops working, it gets this

```
Response code 200
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA***UQAAAAAA1Zs8c********2BOb2tCc%3D3ZnSGsQXhWUKow4c3******M1ZNVIBw1l***SJ6w9X"}

    Response code 400
    {"errors":[{"code":86,"message":"This method requires a GET or HEAD."}]}
```

U can see im getting a bearer token and then i get that from my api call to

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=dualbooks_es
```

Here the code:

```
private static String encodeKeys() {
    try{
    // URL encode the consumer key and secret
    String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
    String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

    // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
    // encoded consumer secret

    String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

    // Base64 encode the string
    String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return base64Encoded;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

// Constructs the request for requesting a bearer token and returns that token as a string
private static String requestBearerToken(String endPointUrl){
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    String encodedCredentials = encodeKeys();

    try {
        URL url = new URL(endPointUrl); 
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"); 
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        writeRequest(connection, "grant_type=client_credentials");

        // Parse the JSON response into a JSON mapped object to fetch fields from.
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(readResponse(connection));

        if (obj != null) {
            String tokenType = (String)obj.get("token_type");
            String token = (String)obj.get("access_token");
            return ((tokenType.equals("bearer")) && (token != null)) ? token : "";
        }
        return new String();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return "";
}

// Fetches the first tweet from a given user's timeline
private static JSONArray fetchTimelineTweet(String endPointUrl){
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;   
    try {
        URL url = new URL(endPointUrl); 
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "api.twitter.com");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Espartapp");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Parse the JSON response into a JSON mapped object to fetch fields from.
        JSONArray obj = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(readResponse(connection));

        if (obj != null) {
            return obj;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

// Reads a response for a given connection and returns it as a string.
private static String readResponse(HttpsURLConnection connection) {
    try {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br;
        Log.d("Respose code", "Code "+connection.getResponseCode());
        if(connection.getResponseCode() !=200)
        {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        Log.d("codigo != 200", ""+str.toString());
        }
        else{
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            Log.d("codigo == 200", str.toString());
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return new String();
}
```

That error code its no listed here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses at the bottom of the page.

**Iphone APP is doing exactly the same and works fine, this was working since last week.**

I can post Objective-C code if u want.

I feel really lost on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So nobody knows anything about this.

I found the solution.

```
   connection.setDoOutput(false);
   connection.setDoInput(true);
```

setDoOutput should be false for the request.

That solves the error.